# Add half size view using storyboard in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to add a half size view on a parent view.
When I push a button on the parent view, the half size view appear, then I push the rest of the screen(the area half size view doesn't cover), the half size view disappear.
When the half size view appear, I don't want let the parent view scroll.

I've written the following code, however the parent view scrolls in this case.
Please tell me how I should do.

```
func tapPickView(){
var storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Answer", bundle: nil)

var controller : AnswerViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AnswerVC") as! AnswerViewController
controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
var answerView = controller.view
self.view.addSubview(answerView)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using following code, I've got what I wanted!

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add a full size overlay `UIButton` with transparent background image under your half size view and above your parent view. The `UIButton` will fire an action to dismiss the half size view.

The overlay `UIButton` can take over all the user interaction events sent to the parent view.

Comment: In that case,it can be scrolled. I don't wanna let view scroll when half size view appears.
Should I use half size view controller?

Comment: @yomihito Sorry I didn't make it clear. What I was trying to say is that you can add a full size overlay UIButton between the half size view and the scroll view, therefore the UIButton will intercept all the touch events sent to the scroll view.

Comment: I'd got it.I'll try your advice!:)

Comment: It seems, it cannot work.I'll postpone it. Thx you:)

Comment: Hi! Song Chenwen!
By using following code, I've got what I wanted! Thx for your help:)
tableView.scrollEnabled = false